# Can I access media libraries on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to know if I can access the media libraries on an iPhone: **Music Library, Video Library, Photo Library**.

I know that I can access the Photo Library (read), but can I add/remove images add new ones?

The same is for Music and Video Libraries... can I access them and **manipulate the files from my application** (add/remove)?

My goal is to synchronize the Media Libraries with an online storage service.

Any thought is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read all the media files from the device as long as the user gives you the permission to do so using the `AssetsLibrary.framework` **BUT** there is no way you can modify or remove the items in there. Imagine what would that mean: every application could go in and modify and/or delete your media items. That's not something you may want....

For more information about the `AssetsLibrary.framework` check this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html).

Comment: `AssetsLibrary.framework` is deprecated. Apps **can** modify a photo library.